# C programming: Division in an if-statement

Tags: c, if-statement

**Why does it print 2 when the value of SIZE is greater than -1?**

Link to the code: http://ideone.com/VCdrKy

```
#include <stdio.h>
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
#define SIZE (sizeof(array)/sizeof(int))

int main(void) {
    if(-1<=SIZE) printf("1");
    else printf("2");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never mix signed and unsigned. The result of `sizeof` is `size_t` which is an unsigned integer and `-1` is a signed integer.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165282/my-computer-thinks-that-signed-int-is-smaller-then-1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981790/what-causes-the-array-in-the-following-code-not-to-be-printed.

Answer (score 1):

Both arguments are in different type

Argument are 'converted' to 'common' type, and 'common' between signed -1 and unsigned  SIZE is unsigned.

So -1 is converted -> 0xfffffff (depends on architecture) that is grater than SIZE

Answer (score 1):

From the C standard on integer conversions:

> If the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than
>   or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, the operand
>   with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with
>   unsigned integer type.

Here -1 is of type `int`, and `SIZE` is of type `size_t`. On your c compiler, `size_t` is unsigned and has greater than or equal rank to `int`, so the `-1` is converted to `size_t`, which gives a large positive number (`SIZE_MAX`)